# Alignment of item of a rowlayout which is in a Groupbox

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing a UI where I have made two buttons and two labeltextfield. The problem is that the alignment I cant do of the inner item in rowlayout. And the buttons are also not anchored to the base of the textfield. I have already set the anchor.bottom to textfield.bottom.

I set the Layout.Alignment = Qt.AlignBottom but isnt working

```
GroupBox{
    id: gb

RowLayout{
    id:rl
    Button{
        id: btn1
        text:"Btn1"
        Layout.preferredHeight: 30
        Layout.preferredWidth: 150
        anchors.bottom: tlfield.bottom
    }

    Button{
        id: btn2
        text:"Btn2"
        Layout.preferredHeight: 30
        Layout.preferredWidth: 150
        anchors.bottom: tlfield.bottom
    }

    LabeledTextFieldVertical
    {
        id: tlfield
        fieldLabel.text: "text"
        fieldText.text: check
        fieldText.maximumLength: 15
        Layout.preferredWidth: 130
        fieldText.height:30
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
        shouldFillWidth: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix layouts and anchors. If you make a picture of how you want it I can propose a solution with only layouts, or only anchors, what do you like?

Comment: That would be of great help, whatever appropriate you feel you can answer.

Comment: You can edit the question to insert a picture

Answer (score 0):

Layouts and anchoring items are two different mechanisms, see [Qt Quick Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-overview.html) and [Positioning with Anchors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html) for further reading.